# Python to wait for zip file to be in folder

Tags: python, operating-system

How to wait for a zip file to be located in folder to continue the code?

I have been working on the code bellow, but it proceeds even when the zip file is not in folder.

```
folder = os.listdir(path)
for file in folder:
    print(file)
    if not file.endswith('.zip'):
        time.sleep(5)
    if file.endswith('.zip'):
        print('zip located')
        break
else:
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: You will have to use a `while True` loop that sleeps for `n` time while checking if the zip is present before continuing (`break` out of the loop). `for` loop is not appropriate for this task, since the loop will eventually break when it reaches the last file in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to this effect should work:

```py
import os
import time

while not '.zip' in [os.path.splitext(file)[1] for file in os.listdir(".")]:
    time.sleep(2)

print('zip located')
```

Comment: Thank you! I dont know how to code this in other situations: `[os.path.splitext(file)[1] for file in os.listdir(".")]`, what should i search for to learn more about it?

Comment: Easier to split up by concepts. The `[... for ... in ...]` is called [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension); [`os.path.splittext()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) is simply splitting `filename.ext` into `[filename, .ext]`; [`os.listdir(".")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) returns a list of all files in the current (`.`) directory. To combine all the concepts, we are creating a list that holds the extensions of all of the files in the directory; i.e. `[".zip", ".csv", ".txt", ".py"]`.